# Algorithm to find geohashes which satisfy query condition

Tags: algorithm, research, geohash

I have an application where I need to query geohashes by specifying the bounding rectangle. Since geohashes map 2D to 1D is there a method by which I may find the prefixes of all geohashes which satisfy the query condition (bounding rectangle). I tried to google but I did not find any algorithm.

It will be great if there is some library which does that for me efficiently in C/c++. Even if there is no library then too I can can work with an algorithmic solution.

Comment: Are you looking for a PostGIS answer or just a general one.  You have this marked as PostGIS but looks like you are looking for a C/C++ library you can plug directly into your app.

Comment: @LR1234567 Sorry for the blunder. I have untagged postgis. but do u know of any such c/c++ library

Answer (score 2):

Even though this isn't a PostGIS question hopefully this will help.

It's my understanding that all solutions to a bounding box geohash must start with the bounding box hash. So here is a demonstration from PostGIS world.

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(ST_MakeEnvelope(12.45, 41.8, 12.49, 41.99,4326 ));
```

Gives a geohash of: sr2

Now normally in PostGIS, I'd just use an overlap query like so:

```
SELECt ST_GeoHash(geog)
  from ch16.places 
   WHERE ST_MakeEnvelope(12.45, 41.8, 12.49, 41.99,4326 )::geography && geog;
```

Which gives me an answer of two records with geohashes

```
sr2y7kk22cyn9mjrg1z8
sr2yk528gwvjw4jn7q0m
```

Note how they all start with  sr2.

Note that an equivalent albeit slower approach(unless I have a functional index on ST_GeoHash) would be:

```
SELECT ST_GeoHash(geog)
 FROM ch16.places 
  WHERE ST_GeoHash(geog) LIKE ST_GeoHash(ST_MakeEnvelope(12.45, 41.8, 12.49, 41.99,4326 )) || '%';
```

Would give me the same answer.  So in short I could be wrong, but I think the solution to any GeoHash bounding box filter is any geohash that starts with the geohash of the bounding box.

At a certain point if you make your bounding box big enough, it has no geohash which in short means your bounding box is too big to be satisfied by a geohash query.